# Error when extracting xml file from compresed zip file created by PHP web service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, zip

I have created web service (client) in PHP (which uses SOAP protocol) that downloads list of ID's for users that want receive messages.

Now they've changed system (on server side) of delivering list of ID's. They have split xml list of more than 200000 ID's in 7 files and encoded them in base64 and compressed in zip file. I have managed to download every file via my PHP client, decode them from base64, then I have created UTF-8 zip file and wrote contents of message in it as you can see in part of my script here:

```
<?php
$obj = array('PinsCcIdsAsXmlZipBase64' => "", 'EmptyPage' => FALSE);

$PageNum=0;
while(!$obj['EmptyPage']){
    $obj=Send_SOAP_mssg($TipPoruke,$SERVICE_TEST,$SOAP_cert,$NAMESPACE_URI,$cert_password,$ServiceId,$PageNum,$obj);
    $zip_file=$OIB_path . 'PinListOfUsersThatDontHavePersonalization' . $PageNum . '.zip';
    $f=fopen($zip_file,"wb")or die("Unable to open file!"); 
    # Now UTF-8 - Add byte order mark 
    fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 
    fwrite($f,$obj['PinsCcIdsAsXmlZipBase64']); 
    fclose($f); 
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    $res = $zip->open($zip_file);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\NIAS\\OIB\\");
        $zip->close();
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR! ' . $res ;
    }
    $PageNum++;
}


function Send_SOAP_mssg($TipPoruke,$SERVICE_TEST,$SOAP_cert,$NAMESPACE_URI,$cert_password,$ServiceId,$PageNum,$obj){

    $client->__getLastRequest();
    $xml=$client->__getLastResponse();

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML( $xml );

    $SOAPRequest = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "EmptyResultSet" );
    if ($SOAPRequest->length!=0){
        $obj['EmptyPage'] = TRUE;
        return $obj;
    }
    else{
        $SOAPRequest = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "PinsCcIdsAsXmlZipBase64" );
        $obj['PinsCcIdsAsXmlZipBase64'] .= base64_decode($SOAPRequest->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $obj['EmptyPage'] = FALSE;
        return $obj;
    }
}
?>
```

Problem occurs when I try to extract content of zip files. I got error 19 (Not a zip archive) as a result of this function
 `$res=$zip->open($zip_file);`. 
Same goes for manually extracting file
[image]

except extracting it with 7-zip, then I don't have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
$obj['PinsCcIdsAsXmlZipBase64'] .= base64_decode($SOAPRequest->item(0)->nodeValue);
// ...
# Now UTF-8 - Add byte order mark
fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));
fwrite($f,$obj['PinsCcIdsAsXmlZipBase64']);
```

`base64_decode` gives you a binary result, this zip content. The `Now UTF-8` comment is false: you have a binary string, the actual zip file. You do not need to add the BOM:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $content = base64_decode("UEsDBAoAAAAAADiaeEkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFABwAYS50eHRVVAkAA8suN1jLLjdYdXgLAAEE6AMAAAToAwAAUEsBAh4DCgAAAAAAOJp4SQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAGAAAAAAAAAAAAKSBAAAAAGEudHh0VVQFAAPLLjdYdXgLAAEE6AMAAAToAwAAUEsFBgAAAAABAAEASwAAAD8AAAAAAA==");
php > $f=fopen("a.zip","wb");
php > fwrite($f,$content);
php > fclose($f);
```

That gives me a correct zip file.

A zip file uses offsets to find its internal structures. If you prepend bytes, these offsets are now wrong: you have a corrupted zip file. 7zip tries (and succeeds) to find the correct value but `ZipArchive` and Windows Compressed Folders don't seem to do that.